# How to test MVC actions with Code First?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, ef-code-first

I'm trying to test MVC actions, so i created IRepository and MockRepository

```
public class Repository : DbContext, IRepository
{
    public IDbSet<TEntity> SomeEntities { get; set; }
}

public interface IRepository : IDisposable
{
    IDbSet<TEntity> SomeEntities { get; set; }

    int SaveChanges();
}
```

With `Create` and `Delete` actions it was simple, but stuck with `Edit` action :

```
    private IRepository repository;

    public ActionResult Edit(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            repository.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            repository.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(entity);
    }
```

So i see two ways to solve this problem:

1. should i add to IRepository new method

   ```
   DbEntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;
   ```

   How i could do this? `DbContext.Entry` method returns very specific `DbEntityEntry<TEntity>` type?
2. or change the way i update entity? What is recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would normally abstract the functionality of EF more than you are, meaning my actions look the following.

```
private IRepository repository;
public ActionResult Edit(TEntity entity)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        repository.Update(entity);
        repository.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(entity);
}
```

then you can easily make a mock repository and test that the desired functions are called.

Note: I normally also separate my entities from my models and manage my unit of work using an action filter, but that's not really related to this post.